# Как задать одинаковое время для анимации прорисовки SVG-элемента и прокрутки страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, анимация, svg-animation

У меня есть SVG-элемент. Анимацию прорисовки его границ я запускаю с привязкой к прокрутке страницы. Вот пример такой анимации:

```js
const htmlElem = document.querySelector("html");
const pathElem = document.querySelector(".path");
const dashOffset = parseInt(getComputedStyle(pathElem).strokeDashoffset);
document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  const percentageComplete =
    (window.pageYOffset / (htmlElem.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight)) * 100;
  const offsetUnit = (percentageComplete * dashOffset) / 100;
  pathElem.style.strokeDashoffset = dashOffset - offsetUnit;
});

//прогресс
let x = $('.progress');
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
  let st = $(window).scrollTop();
  let sa = $(document).height();
  let sb = $(window).height();
  let dd = Math.ceil(100 * (st / (sa - sb)));
  x.css({width : dd + '%'})
})
```

```css
body {margin: 0; height: 3000px;}

.progress {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 0%; height: 5px; background-color: red;}
.progress::after {content: "Крутим вниз"; white-space: nowrap; position: absolute; top: 15px; left: 15px;}

#svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -200px;
}

path {
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  fill: none;
  stroke: darkorange;
  stroke-width: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="progress"></div><!--прогресс-->

<svg id="svg" width="640" height="480">
<g>

<circle fill="orange" stroke="orangered" stroke-width="6px" r="13.53787" cy="287.50003" cx="279.99998"/>

<path class="path" d="m396.35663,311.25821c-13.41742,-10.47318 -28.76758,-3.96683 -43.5509,-4.75632c-12.93182,-11.07962 -28.66629,2.3475 -40.85934,-8.33789c-15.77493,-14.05475 11.56558,-22.86807 5.7373,-39.56415c-0.65771,-24.0419 -10.94836,-45.81717 -21.77539,-66.02428c-7.65988,-16.06839 -4.94803,-34.53508 -7.41699,-51.7166c-8.85388,-12.34473 -17.69766,-27.62405 -7.16412,-42.87289c11.90973,-12.87106 6.30396,-29.77943 1.62924,-44.65391c12.03101,3.54156 25.85321,19.66071 41.68884,16.43285c10.75632,-6.93137 17.29297,-0.08103 19.09409,12.61797c5.64624,16.29109 8.93484,38.5827 26.75375,43.83432c18.70941,5.34254 39.6553,6.52644 54.44867,22.20027c27.06769,25.3474 39.60474,65.31624 38.552,103.83789c2.43921,18.01105 25.04413,8.44919 36.23547,11.10004c18.74976,-0.82904 36.76111,5.06967 54.91443,9.1069c16.20013,4.31042 29.92078,-9.31888 45.14905,-10.9483c2.57037,15.745 -17.41418,22.30164 -28.33221,27.15833c-12.95184,5.51471 -26.98676,5.64691 -40.29266,1.6095c-28.78772,-7.18442 -59.29565,-5.29221 -86.63629,7.31573c-14.76294,5.44357 -29.09103,15.73447 -45.14957,14.43954l-3.02536,-0.77902l0,0l0,0z" />

</g>
</svg>
```

Как показано на примере, анимация заканчивается раньше, чем когда заканчивается прокрутка страницы.

**Вопрос:** Как рассчитать время анимации прорисовки границ SVG-элемента при прокрутке страницы с временем прокрутки страницы, чтобы анимация заканчивалась ровно тогда, когда заканчивается прокрутка страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему не использовать стандартный вариант [pathLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength)?

Ведь если нет каких-то особых предпочтений к указанным значениям `dashoffset/dasharray =2000`, *pathLength* решает все проблемы.

Установить ...

```css
// HTML
<path pathLength="100" ...

// CSS
stroke-dashoffset: 100
stroke-dasharray: 100
```

... и все считать в относительных процентах, как это сделано с progress-ом.

Ниже пример:

```js
const htmlElem = document.querySelector("html")
const progress = document.querySelector(".progress")
const pathElem = document.querySelector(".path")

// Дабавлю относительный калькулятор
function rangeCalculator(begin, end, beginRange = 0, endRange = 100) {
  const inputRange = end - begin
  const outRange = endRange - beginRange
  return /*calculate*/(current) => (
    beginRange + (outRange / (inputRange / (current - begin)))
  )
}

// Сразу создадим функцию расчета относительно scroll
// Есть один момент:
//   Если пользователь изменит размер окна - калькулятор собъется,
//   а значит нужно его перерасчитать
const calculate = (() => {
  let calc
  const remake = () => calc = rangeCalculator(0, htmlElem.scrollHeight - htmlElem.clientHeight)
  window.addEventListener('resize', remake)
  remake()
  // На выходе получим значение в диапазоне 0 - 100
  return (v) => calc(v)
})()

document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  const percent = calculate(htmlElem.scrollTop)
  // Собственно передаем всем подряд наши проценты
  progress.style.width = `${percent}%`
  pathElem.style.strokeDashoffset = 100 - percent
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 3000px;
}

.progress {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

.progress::after {
  content: "Крутим вниз";
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}

#svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -200px;
}

path {
  stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
  fill: none;
  stroke: darkorange;
  stroke-width: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress"></div>

<svg id="svg" width="640" height="480">
    <g>
      <circle fill="orange" stroke="orangered" stroke-width="6px" r="13.53787" cy="287.50003" cx="279.99998" />
      <path class="path" pathLength="100"
        d="m396.35663,311.25821c-13.41742,-10.47318 -28.76758,-3.96683 -43.5509,-4.75632c-12.93182,-11.07962 -28.66629,2.3475 -40.85934,-8.33789c-15.77493,-14.05475 11.56558,-22.86807 5.7373,-39.56415c-0.65771,-24.0419 -10.94836,-45.81717 -21.77539,-66.02428c-7.65988,-16.06839 -4.94803,-34.53508 -7.41699,-51.7166c-8.85388,-12.34473 -17.69766,-27.62405 -7.16412,-42.87289c11.90973,-12.87106 6.30396,-29.77943 1.62924,-44.65391c12.03101,3.54156 25.85321,19.66071 41.68884,16.43285c10.75632,-6.93137 17.29297,-0.08103 19.09409,12.61797c5.64624,16.29109 8.93484,38.5827 26.75375,43.83432c18.70941,5.34254 39.6553,6.52644 54.44867,22.20027c27.06769,25.3474 39.60474,65.31624 38.552,103.83789c2.43921,18.01105 25.04413,8.44919 36.23547,11.10004c18.74976,-0.82904 36.76111,5.06967 54.91443,9.1069c16.20013,4.31042 29.92078,-9.31888 45.14905,-10.9483c2.57037,15.745 -17.41418,22.30164 -28.33221,27.15833c-12.95184,5.51471 -26.98676,5.64691 -40.29266,1.6095c-28.78772,-7.18442 -59.29565,-5.29221 -86.63629,7.31573c-14.76294,5.44357 -29.09103,15.73447 -45.14957,14.43954l-3.02536,-0.77902l0,0l0,0z" />
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавлен коэффициент в строку JS - **1.95**

`(window.pageYOffset / (htmlElem.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight) / 1.95) * 100;`

```js
const htmlElem = document.querySelector("html");
const pathElem = document.querySelector(".path");
const dashOffset = parseInt(getComputedStyle(pathElem).strokeDashoffset);
document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  const percentageComplete =
    (window.pageYOffset / (htmlElem.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight) / 1.95) * 100;
  const offsetUnit = (percentageComplete * dashOffset) / 100;
  pathElem.style.strokeDashoffset = dashOffset - offsetUnit;
});

//прогресс
let x = $('.progress');
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
  let st = $(window).scrollTop();
  let sa = $(document).height();
  let sb = $(window).height();
  let dd = Math.ceil(100 * (st / (sa - sb)));
  x.css({width : dd + '%'})
})
```

```css
body {margin: 0; height: 3000px;}

.progress {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 0%; height: 5px; background-color: red;}
.progress::after {content: "Крутим вниз"; white-space: nowrap; position: absolute; top: 15px; left: 15px;}

#svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -200px;
}

path {
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  fill: none;
  stroke: darkorange;
  stroke-width: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="progress"></div><!--прогресс-->

<svg id="svg" width="640" height="480">
<g>

<circle fill="orange" stroke="orangered" stroke-width="6px" r="13.53787" cy="287.50003" cx="279.99998"/>

<path class="path" d="m396.35663,311.25821c-13.41742,-10.47318 -28.76758,-3.96683 -43.5509,-4.75632c-12.93182,-11.07962 -28.66629,2.3475 -40.85934,-8.33789c-15.77493,-14.05475 11.56558,-22.86807 5.7373,-39.56415c-0.65771,-24.0419 -10.94836,-45.81717 -21.77539,-66.02428c-7.65988,-16.06839 -4.94803,-34.53508 -7.41699,-51.7166c-8.85388,-12.34473 -17.69766,-27.62405 -7.16412,-42.87289c11.90973,-12.87106 6.30396,-29.77943 1.62924,-44.65391c12.03101,3.54156 25.85321,19.66071 41.68884,16.43285c10.75632,-6.93137 17.29297,-0.08103 19.09409,12.61797c5.64624,16.29109 8.93484,38.5827 26.75375,43.83432c18.70941,5.34254 39.6553,6.52644 54.44867,22.20027c27.06769,25.3474 39.60474,65.31624 38.552,103.83789c2.43921,18.01105 25.04413,8.44919 36.23547,11.10004c18.74976,-0.82904 36.76111,5.06967 54.91443,9.1069c16.20013,4.31042 29.92078,-9.31888 45.14905,-10.9483c2.57037,15.745 -17.41418,22.30164 -28.33221,27.15833c-12.95184,5.51471 -26.98676,5.64691 -40.29266,1.6095c-28.78772,-7.18442 -59.29565,-5.29221 -86.63629,7.31573c-14.76294,5.44357 -29.09103,15.73447 -45.14957,14.43954l-3.02536,-0.77902l0,0l0,0z" />

</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно, пожалуйста попробуйте добавить пояснение текстом, отвечающее на вопрос *"Как задать одинаковое время для анимации прорисовки SVG-элемента и прокрутки страницы?"*

Comment: @Kromster код ответа от кода вопроса отличается добавлением в 40 строке  **/1.95**  - называется решение `методом тыка`   **(window.pageYOffset / (htmlElem.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight) / 1.95) * 100;**

Comment: @Alexandr_TT если у вас есть такие сведения, пожалуйста, внесите их правкой в ответ. Не нужно отвечать адресно мне :-)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT ничуть, просто хотелось бы улучшить/"спасти" ответ )